# Adding TextBox in winRT MessageDialog

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm working in windows 8 store application and I'm trying to popup a dialog to let the user enter information in a textbox for example.

How to do that ?

Comment: Did you tried anything so far? Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 5):

The [`InputDialog`](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/4d568d4e4c6a#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/InputDialog/InputDialog.cs) control in WinRT XAML Toolkit does just that. It is basically a Popup control with a TextBox and some buttons. There is a [sample](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/4d568d4e4c6a#WinRTXamlToolkit.Sample/Views/Controls/InputDialogTestPage.xaml.cs) for it too. The most basic one does this:

```
var dialog = new InputDialog();
var result = await dialog.ShowAsync(
    "This is the title",
    "This is the content/message",
    "Option 1",
    "Option 2",
    "Option 3");
```

The result is the string that is used on the button that was clicked - e.g. "Option 1".

Comment: These days though - I would use a [`ContentDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Using "Callisto" library, for those kind of custom Dialog box is the best option.
Check out this library by elaborating it's Code Samples.
[Callisto Code Samples](https://github.com/timheuer/callisto).

I really bothered by this problem and found this solution very help full.
you can add anything you want in the Custom dialog box.